High Voltage Dielectric Tester and Sparking Damage
Background: We have a dielectric tester that creates 2500V DC, at low amperage of course. 5mA max. The tester is designed to produce 2500V potential and be connected to a device under test (DUT). The device under test cannot conduct more than 3mA but probably shouldn't or won't conduct more than 0mA. We use an A/D converter to measure transmitted voltage and thus current into the DUT.
Problem: The problem comes when a DUT is built incorrectly with a small gap potential, like a spark plug, and connected to the tester. There might be 1mm or less between the +, - terminals in the DUT. So at 2500V DC it creates a continuous stream of sparks. These sparks get back into the circuit that controls the tester and damage many other components.
Question: How do we stop these sparks and also detect them? Would a TVS or Schottky diode work and how to best put these into practice? We need to stop them from damaging other components and also detect them so that we can fail the DUT.


The A/D gets damaged at times. Sometimes the transformers are damaged maybe, possibly the FET. The results vary and I have not had time to diagnose the failures.
If we were to add in HF blockers or decoupling caps, how would we detect the failure? it seems like it would not fail in the same way. We need to sense that the 1mm gap is there and is a problem.

Thanks all for your comments! It's an interesting problem.

Add a resistor (1->5 k) across C2 and correct the attenuation factor with R21. Note that you need (perhaps) compensate this capacitor vs frequency by adding some capacities around all 10 Meg resistors ...


How do we stop these sparks and also detect them?

If you are monitoring the voltage on the tester, you would see this as a voltage drop. Or if you are monitoring the current you would see the current spike above 3mA.
To protect the equipment you could use a TVS diode if you already have a series resistor to protect the ADC. One problem I see with the HV+ connected to the ADS 1015 is there is no resistor divider, so the protection diodes on the ADS1015 could be activated and pull full current from the supply through the resistor. This is probably happening if you have any LRC effects happening with the cables and the device where overshoot on the HV- line is blowing out the ADC (but that is my guess).
It would be better to do a differential current sense with an opamp and then feed that voltage into the ADC, you'll get better readings.

There is a divider to the ADC: 5Mohm to 50k on the bottom and into the A/D. Agreed on the opamp.
There are 3 TVS's in there. Is there a better way to disipate the energy?

Yeah, you can use a MOV, a gas discharge tube. A GDT might be a bit much

Adding inductors in series at the two HV terminals helps a lot, first aid is a ferrite around each terminal wire. The pulses will be stretched in time, which reduces voltage.
The resistive divider chain also is a capacitive divider because the resistors have an internal capacitance. When I assume only 1 pF across R45-R49 and around 10 pF from there to GND via D5, R6, R12. A 2 kV falling edge at the HV+ terminal would still create a -200 V transient across D5. Most of the energy will be taken by the TVS, but not all of it.
The same effect exists across the other divider chain, so adding capacitors across D5, D6 and D1 will help here.
Using unidirectional TVS elements would better clamp negative transients. The circuit is not designed to process voltages below GND anyway.
Have a look at the GND paths. Such fast gradients can produce voltage drops across even wide tracks. A picture of the layout would be helpful.
The coupling of the transients through the two CCFL transformers back to the primary side seams to be properly handled by C11 and C12.
EDIT
The second part of the question was, how to detect such external sparks from inside the HV generator. I want to suggest this circuit.

V1 is the HV output with the sharp falling edge of a spark.
C1 is a 33 pF / 10 kV ceramic cap, that decouples the HV DC and feeds the transient into the transformer
The transformer 750082154 from Würth is tiny and has an isolation voltage of 3 kVAC, which was required to protect the circuit.
C2 together with the secondary winding forms a resonant tank, where the energy circulates.
R1 and D1 clamp the tank signal between -0.5 and +7.5 V and this signal triggers the set input of the flipflop multiple times during a spark.
SW_RESET will clear the stored spark event.

I used a 10 V supply for these CMOS NOR gates just to show the idea.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The simulator shows this behaviour:

I soldered a test circuit to verify the function.

The real world signals are not far away from the simulator. Please excuse the excessive ringing in the tracks, I was lazy and used long alligator clips to connect the scope.
The yellow track is the input of the NOR gate, the green track is the flipflop output.


Interesting thoughts! I had to digest for a bit. So adding 1-5pf on each of the diodes could dissipate some of the HF energy?
The TVS's could be unidirectional and you think that would help with a ground bounce?
The board is laid out with significant spacings and even some air gaps in places to help and seems to be working well in that regard - I think it is more of a component/design problem.

To give better hints I need to know which components died.

These are great hints already! Thanks so much!
